# Download a file over HTTP into a byte array in C#?

Tags: arrays, http, file, download, byte

I'm trying to read a file that I have a web address for into a byte array.  I've been using `File.ReadAllBytes` to read files locally and I've been unable to figure out the cleanest way to do this for a file on the web.

I imagine this is just a quick snippet of code, but everything I can find through search is only for local files.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
byte[] response = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(url);
```

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks for the speedy response!

Comment: Not sure if that WebClient will dispose, better to wrap it in a using surely?

Comment: @JL. The irony is that LeakyCode wrote the answer. :-)

Comment: If you simply call `DownloadData`, not calling Dispose would not be too bad. Unlike handling `WebRequest` manually, it's not gonna leave an open TCP connection hanging or things like that.

Comment: You should be careful when using `WebClient` for downloading multiple files. It doesn't support concurrent I/O operations. If you want to download multiple files you can create multiple `WebClient` instances.